# Error while installing monodevelop "Error executing tool '/usr/local/bin/mcs.exe' "

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop, linux-mint

I tried installing monodevelop using:

sudo apt-get install monodevelop

and it installed it just fine, but when I try launching it nothing happens.
I tried launching it from terminal and no errors, it just returns 0 right away.

> monodevelop
>
> echo $?   return 0.

So, I decided to download it from git.
I did the ./configure and when I try makeing it I get the following error:

Build FAILED.

Warnings:

/home/matt/monodevelop/main/Main.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/matt/monodevelop/main/external/raygun4net/Mindscape.Raygun4Net/Mindscape.Raygun4Net.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) ->

```
/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' not resolved
```

Errors:

/home/matt/monodevelop/main/Main.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/matt/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libstetic/libstetic.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

```
/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Error executing tool '/usr/local/bin/mcs.exe': ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/mcs.exe', CommandLine='/noconfig @/tmp/tmp7bbfd119.tmp', CurrentDirectory='/home/matt/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libstetic'

 1 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.7515590
make[2]: *** [sln_build] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/matt/monodevelop/main'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/matt/monodevelop/main'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

I searched for hours and could not find an answer.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what version of mono are you using? what version of monodevelop did you try to install via apt-get ?

Comment: I got newest mono from git.  And all I typed via apt-get was monodevelop, so I assume the newest one available for linux mint 16.

Comment: if you got your mono from git, what's likely is that you didn't install it properly, please explain how did you install it

Comment: I got the dependencies, cd mono -> ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local -> make -> sudo make install

Comment: and by the way, in monodevelop I write ./configure --prefix=/usr  If I do ./configure --prefix=/usr/local I get over 700 errors

Comment: yup, that's the proof that your new mono (installed in /usr/local) is the culprit

Comment: I overall recommend that you migrate to Ubuntu 14.04 (which includes a very recent mono and monodevelop) if you don't know what you're doing

Comment: If you could give me some pointers I could maybe figure it out. What do you think is wrong with the installation?

Comment: I don't know, I made a sample c# program and I could compile it and run using mono. Seems like everything is working fine...

Comment: you probably compiled it with the mono that your distro supplies, not with the one you installed

Comment: when I try compiling with --prefix=/usr/local I get errors too. Even more errors actually.

Comment: because your new mono install to /usr/local is likely incorrect